Bounding the Determinant of a Matrix by its Frobenius norm?
I'm almost sure I've done something wrong, and could use some input about it if possible.
Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ square matrix with positive real entries.
Let $B = A^T A$, so that $B$ is positive definite and symmetric. Then note that the matrix logarithm is given by $a(B^{\frac{1}{a}} - I) \sim \ln(B)$ (which approaches $\ln(B)$ from above) as $ a \rightarrow \infty$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.
So we can write $\det(B) = \det(e^{\ln(B)}) = e^{\operatorname{tr} \left( \ln(B) \right) } \leq  e^{\operatorname{tr} \left( a(B^{\frac{1}{a}} - I) \right) } = e^{a \operatorname{tr} \left(B^{\frac{1}{a}} - I \right) }  = e^{a( \operatorname{tr} \left(B^{\frac{1}{a}} \right) - n) }$.
And by the Araki-Lieb-Thirring inequality: $ \operatorname{tr} \left(B^{\frac{1}{a}} \right) \leq (\operatorname{tr} \left(B \right))^{{\frac{1}{a}}}$. So that:
$e^{a( \operatorname{tr} \left(B^{\frac{1}{a}} \right) - n) } \leq e^{a((\operatorname{tr} \left(B \right))^{{\frac{1}{a}}} - n) }  = e^{-a (n-1) + \epsilon(a, B) } e^{\ln(\operatorname{tr} \left(B \right))} = e^{-a (n-1) + \epsilon(a, B) } \operatorname{tr} \left(B \right) $, where $ \epsilon(a, B)$ is the error incurred from truncating the limiting form of the logarithm at some finite $a$.
Finally,
$|\det(A)| = \sqrt{\det(B)} \leq e^{-\frac{1}{2} ( a(n-1) + \epsilon(a, B)) } \sqrt{\operatorname{tr} \left(B \right)} 
 = e^{-\frac{1}{2} ( a(n-1) + \epsilon(a, B)) } 
  \|A\|_\text{F} $.
Where did I go wrong?

The directions of both inequalities $\ln(B)\leq a(B^{1/a} - I)$ and $\operatorname{tr}\left(B^{1/a}\right) \leq (\operatorname{tr} \left(B \right))^{1/a}$ should be reversed.

But since $B$ is diagonalizable with positive eigenvalues, we have that $\operatorname{tr} \left( \ln(B)  \right) =   \sum_{i=1}^n  \ln( \lambda i) \leq \sum{i=1}^n a(\lambda _i^{\frac{1}{a}} - 1) = \operatorname{tr} \left( a(B^{\frac{1}{a}} - 1)   \right)$. Where the inequality comes from: https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.5 (4.5.5). So why would the first inequality mentioned by reversed? @user1551

My bad. I have mistaken it with another inequality. But still, the direction of the inequality $\operatorname{tr}(B^{1/a})\le\left(\operatorname{tr}(B)\right)^{1/a}$ should be reversed.

Ah gotcha, ya I see it now. Thanks!
